# Trigger an API call after an event takes place in Quickbooks?

Tags: api, salesforce, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to trigger an API call after an event takes place in Quickbooks? For example, if a user adds a bill to Quickbooks, it would make an API call to our Salesforce.com app and create a new 'Bill' record in our Salesforce org. This would allow us to use our Salesforce workflow to trigger an approval process for the bill to be paid (approved by manager, create task for bookkeeper, etc), without the bill ever having to be manually input into two separate systems.

I know that I can do it the other way around (input the bill into Salesforce, have it push the record to Quickbooks and simultaneously launch the approval process), however, Quickbooks has the ability to remember vendor/account information that, for large companies, is an invaluable time-saver.

Any idea if it is possible to trigger these events on the Quickbooks side? Thanks!

Comment: IF you could provide more information we can better answer. If you are referring to QuicKBooks for Windows you can use the QBXML SDK to integrate and receive an event as you describe. However if you want to use the REST APIs instead you can poll for the changed data and update Salesforce as soon as a new bill is added.

Comment: Also, we are working on adding webhooks for the QuicKBooks API as well, https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/03/11/discussing-webhooks

Comment: Thanks @JarredKeneally, we are in the early stages of building a client-facing app that may or may not end up using QB as its back end, however, a feature like webhooks would be a big plus in the QB column as far as what we use as our backend accounting database. Any idea when we can expect to see a feature like this released to developers? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a polling service which will keep querying bill entity in certain interval. If it finds a new entry then you can query that using getByID endpoint and enter that bill in your app.

You can setup a custom integration using QBSDK.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

There is a thread on this in IPP's blog. 
https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/03/11/discussing-webhooks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Intuit does not support webhooks at this time for APIs but only for QBXML.